# How do I use my custom useFetch hook when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Semi-new to React. I have a useFetch hook that has all of my fetch functionality, and I want to call it to fetch the next page of items when the user clicks a "load more items" button.

Obviously,

`<button onClick={() => { useFetch(...) }}>load more items<button>` won't work because I'm calling a custom hook inside a callback. What is the best pattern in general for doing this kind of thing? I can call useFetch in the functional component itself but then fetch will happen when the component mounts, which isn't really what I want.

Everything I've read points to the usefulness of making fetching a hook, but it's just made it harder to work with, especially when I have to fetch small chunks frequently and dynamically.

edit: I may have figured it out, I'll post again with the answer if it works and this post doesn't receive an answer

Comment: Custom fetch hooks generally return a function to call to make a fetch request, and also return status of the request, including errors. What is ***your*** `useFetch` hook implementation and how is ***your*** code using it, or trying to use it?

Comment: @DrewReese useFetch just fetches data from the provided url and does a try catch along with checking for status code errors. It has a useEffect which calls the defined fetchData function and exports the stateful data value. Should I instead just define the function and return the function and that's it? Then, make sure I fetch inside of a useEffect in the files that use it?

Comment: Are you asking us how to use the custom `useFetch` hook that you're not sharing with us so we can't say how to use it? Or are you asking about how to write a custom `useFetch` hook that is actually usable? Either way, these aren't very answerable questions and we'd need more context. The purpose of custom hooks is to encapsulate reusable code to be used in React function components.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't call a hook from an event handler, as you've noticed yourself.

Your useFetch() hook usually shouldn't fetch any data, but rather return a function that you can call to fetch data afterwards.

Your component would then look something like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { fetch, data } = useFetch();
  return (<div>
      <p>{data}</p>
      <button onClick={() => fetch()}>Load more items</button>
    </div>);
}
```

Your `useFetch` hook is then responsible for

- Creating a `fetch` function.
- Returning `data` once `fetch` has been called and resolved.
- Keeping `data` in state, and updating `data` if `fetch` is called again.

Here's what the `useFetch` hook might look like

```
function useFetch() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const fetch = async () => {
    const result = await // call to your API, or whereever you get data from
    setData(result.data);
  };

  return { fetch, data };
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, should I be setting state inside the useFetch still? I have setData when I successfully fetch, should I be returning that along with the fetch function reference?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes, that would be a fine way to do it. I'll edit my answer slightly to reflect this.

Comment: I'm still not able to get it to work, can you give me a bare bones implementation of what useFetch would look like for the above to work?

Comment: Sure, I've added a quick bare bones implementation of the hook. It basically keeps data in state, creates a fetch function that sets data when called, and returns both the fetch function and the data. In this example the data is undefined until fetch is called, but you can initialize it with whatever data you like.

Comment: hmm this is concerning. It's still not working for me. I'm using fetch in a useEffect and then trying to do something with the data, but it keeps returning undefined. Should I link the relevant part of my code?

Comment: So I'm trying to fetch data and do something with it on page load. When I try to access the data after fetching it returns undefined. Is this a problem with async? Sometimes on live reload I can see that logging the data works, but when the page loads, it doesn't work. I have them both in a useEffect, and I've tried separating them into two useEffects

Comment: Why are you calling the function from an effect? And what are you trying to do with the data afterwards?

Comment: If I don't call it from an effect, the calls to setData rerender the component and cause an infinite loop. I'm just trying to set another state value in the component related to the json. I got it to work but I have to use a useEffect for the fetch with no dependencies and then another useEffect to set the state value "someStateValue" with a data dependency. I'm sure there's a better way than calling 2 useEffects for every fetch

Comment: You're definitely doing something wrong, but it's impossible to tell without seeing your code :-)

Comment: So what's the difference jinstead of  export a simple  fetch function ? If the `useFEtch` returns a function , then why not just export a simple `fetch` function ? why use `useFetch` thingy ?

Answer (score 3):

Ah! The hooks in React.

One way to do this would be to define your functions in the useFetch method which are responsible for making the API calls and then return those functions from the hook to be used wherever you want to.

For example, a useFetch hook would look like this

```
const useFetch = () => {
  const makeApiCall = () => {};
  
  return {
    makeApiCall
  }
}
```

and then inside your component

```
const Comp = () => {
  const { makeApiCall } = useFetch();
  
  return (
    <Button onClick={makeApiCall} />
  )
}
```

You can always pass some relevant info to the hook and return more relevant data from the hook.

Comment: awesome thanks, not what I had in mind but I'll try this out